# How to join and get number of rows in groups - all in one data.table statement?

Tags: r, data.table

I try to do

```
library(data.table)

customers <- data.table( id=c(1,2,3,4),                               # id of customers
                         name=c("Frank","Hans","Peter","Markus"),
                         age=c(22,34,64,19))
purchases <- data.table( id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),                           # id of purchases
                         customer_id=c(1,2,4,2,1,5), 
                         name=c("CD","hairdryer","book","glas","paper","chair"),
                         product_type=c("home","home","home","home","office","office")
                         )

purchases[customers, .N, by=product_type, on=c(customer_id = "id")]
purchases[customers, mean(age), by=product_type, on=c(customer_id = "id")]
```

and expected for the first join

```
   product_type N
1:         home 4
2:           NA 1
3:       office 1
```

but got

```
   product_type N
1:         home 4
2:           NA 1
3:         home 1
```

The second command was supposed to do a join, then group on `product_type` and calculate the mean of age for each of those groups. However I get the error that `age` was not found.

```
purchases[customers, mean(age), by=.EACHI, on=c(customer_id = "id")]
```

works splendidly, by the way.

Comment: Try `purchases[customers, on = c(customer_id = "id")][, .N, product_type]`

Comment: @akrun: Sure, but I'd like to have it in one command, so that it's fast. Otherwise I could just use `dplyr`.

Comment: There is a feature request for this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/733

Comment: @Make42 I think in `dplyr` you would need to use even more commands.

Comment: @jangorecki: Your missing the point of efficiency: The big gain would be that if `data.table` knows that I am only interested in the `age` column on `product_type` groups, it would not have to process the entire two tables, but only relevant columns during the *join* (already!).

Comment: @Make42I agree this operation could be improved (as FR linked by Frank) but even without having it implemented, as is now, you will get way more scalable solution with data.table

Comment: @Make42 I doubt it would make a noticeable difference, but you can achieve the efficiency you're looking for by doing `purchases[customers, .(product_type), on = c(customer_id = "id")][, .N, by = product_type]`